# Setting custom Open XML metadata

Tags: openxml, ole, office-2007, docx, xlsx

**Background**

Custom properties in Open XML are stored in `docProps/custom.xml` and look like this (for a string):

```
<property fmtid="{xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" pid="2" name="Key">
    <vt:lpwstr>Value</vt:lpwstr>
</property>
```

The Open XML (v1) specification doesn't give many details about `fmtid` and `pid`. It merely states in section 7.3.2.2:

> [PID] Uniquely relates a custom property with an OLE property

**Questions**

I have a few questions about the specification's vague explanation:

1. What are OLE properties?
2. Is it possible add a new OpenXML property in custom.xml without storing an OLE property?
3. Does `pid` need to be unique per `fmtid`, or unique for all `fmtid`s in custom.xml
4. **Why don't my own properties in custom.xml appear in Word?**

Comment: @otaku, that doesn't answer my questions. I need to add, not remove, properties, so a deeper understanding of custom.xml is necessary.

Comment: Otaku, please re-read my question. I'm not looking for a black-box C# function. I want to understand the connection between the Open XML properties in docProps/custom.xml and the filesystem-level NTFS properties that Office itself uses. The thread you posted doesn't *explain* how properties are implemented. Furthermore, to address your last point, adding properties to custom.xml seems to *never* make them appear in Office. Don't tell me it does until you've tried it.

Comment: If you downvote, please explain what was "unclear or not useful" about this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to partially answer my own question based on what I discovered by experimenting.

1. OLE properties are NTFS extended attributes that are stored in alternative file streams. They can be viewed or modified with [DSOfile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850671/why-do-custom-file-properties-set-using-the-dsofile-library-not-persist-after-s) StackOverflow question.
2. Custom properties can be added by modifying custom.xml. They will only appear in Word's properties dialog if the fmtid belongs to Word or a loaded COM add-in.