# Manage file custom properties (Get&Set) programmatically - C#

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a C# Windows console application to manage files in Windows Explorer. At this point of my work I need to create file custom properties and both set and get their values. I've read many web articles, and I understand that I can't do this for each file, it depends on the type/nature of the selected file... and this is ok for me, this is a limit that I took into account and accepted before starting my work.

Please consider that I want to manage these properties without using the file related application (for example, in case of a .docx file I don't want to open the Word application and then work with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document` classes). Cases do in fact exist where it is possible to right-click on a file in Win Explorer, select 'Properties' and then find a tab named as 'Custom' where you can search, read and set custom properties.

[image]

What I want to do is manage (Read & Write) this file Custom information programmatically.

Any hint? Thanks!

**EDIT #1:**
I tried to follow the [Simon Mourier's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451540/extracting-windows-file-properties-custom-properties-c-sharp/35622540#35622540) but unfortunately it does not work, I was not able to SET the property value. I tried also the [Rod Howarth's hint](http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-file.html) but it fails when you try to set the value of an existing custom property... moreover, using the `DSOFile library` there are [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850671/why-do-custom-file-properties-set-using-the-dsofile-library-not-persist-after?rq=1) related to the persistence of the saved custom property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://scatteredcode.net/tutorials/c-add-and-edit-ntfs-custom-properties/) solution seems working fine if you need to set the value of an existing custom property; if you need to create a new born custom property, then you must use the `Add(string sPropName, ref object Value)` method of the `CustomProperties` collection.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451540/extracting-windows-file-properties-custom-properties-c-sharp/35622540#35622540). It is about office file custom properties, but there is one answer describing the method how to get custom properties of any file (as far as I anderstood, even txt file can have some)